# How to build a freshly init'ed React Native app for tvOS?

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, tvos

Starting with a fresh project (RN 0.60), created using:

```
react-native init ProjectName
```

I'm able to build and successfully deploy for iOS, but how do I build for tvOS and execute in a tvOS simulator?

I see tvOS build targets, but attempting to build said target results in:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-ProjectName-tvOS
```

The path forward seems unclear, partially because of legacy information about how to build/run on tvOS before Doug Louder's stuff was merged.